# Cannot load css in Django template

Tags: python, html, css, django

Here is my reduced html code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <link href="{% static '/css/buttonform.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
</html>
```

And here is my *settings.py***:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles',]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),
)
```

The css file exists in the STATICFILES_DIRS but the error comes as: `Not Found: /css/buttonform.css`

Comment: How about without the leading slash? `{% static 'css/buttonform.css' %}`

Comment: @alecxe It worked! But the again, in the [Django Tutorial](https://youtu.be/lAJLUYmgwLY?list=PLEsfXFp6DpzRcd-q4vR5qAgOZUuz8041S) the bootstrap css part is having a leading / slash before the path, why is that so?

Comment: Hm, when the presenter shows the templates, I see the static path not starting with slash - for example [here](https://youtu.be/lAJLUYmgwLY?t=425).

Comment: @alecxe Yes I just realized! It was a syntax error and the same error was shown. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<link href="{% static '/css/buttonform.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="{% static 'css/buttonform.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: the extra slash at the beginning of the path means "root directory", so it would try to find it starting at your app directory, without it, it would look for the file starting at the static folder. The issue here is your stylesheet never gets loaded into your html because it can't find it in the first place.